# Executing jQuery code when visiting a page with anchor tag in the URL

Tags: jquery, anchor

On a certain page, I want to execute jQuery code when: (1) the user arrives to that page from a different page, and (2) through a URL that has an anchor tag in it (site.com/page#anchor_tag). Is that possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) check `document.referer` to see if you came from a different page.

For (2) you can use `window.location.hash` to get the part of the URL beginning with `#`.